# Add Laravel .env variable to Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, environment-variables, laravel-mix

I would like to get access to an .env variable using Vue JS.

In my .env file I have added the 'MIX_' prefix to the var.

```
MIX_VAR=key
```

And then in the vue component, I have in the created():

```
console.log(process.env.MIX_VAR);
```

I keep getting undefined as the result.

I have tried clearing config cache, but still getting the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this done via ajax? You can access the env variables via the controller using the `env()` helper.

Comment: I've found this not to be secure, the values of the variables are brought through to the application app.js file

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must build your JS for the env variables to be replaced. You can do this with `npm` or `yarn`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#running-mix

Comment: thats worked for me by adding a new variable in env file with this prefix : MIX_  but need to restart php artisan serve and also restart npm run watch....

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#environment-variables

Comment: @darryl-e-clarke (if you want) can you accept the other new answer voted in the last three months by StackOverflow users? ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/60378481/308578

Comment: Will i have to restart npm and serve command everytime I change url?
If yes then how would i run npm run watch on cpanel if i dont have it?

Answer (score 30):

**in windows :**

thats worked for me without any require in webpack.mix

... just add a new variable in env file with this prefix : **MIX_**

```
MIX_API_URL=http://laravel:8000
```

but need to restart php artisan serve and also restart npm run watch....

```
  let api_url = process.env.MIX_API_URL;
  console.log("my env variable:");
  console.log(api_url);
```

**in linux or docker:**

i didnt use them yet

Comment: myserver is windows but it didnt work in docker. i dont know why

Comment: In my case, it doesn't work neither way  :/ with or without `require('dotenv').config();`

Comment: @Pathros you need to stop (php artisan serve) and run again for any changes in env file ... did you test it ? check it please

Comment: I am using Laravel Homestead. I have restarted the server many times and the MIX_ variables are not being identified / pulled. I don't understand why. What am I missing?

Comment: @Pathros what about your local or development pc?

Answer (score 11):

Pulled from the official docs @ https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#environment-variables

---

**Environment Variables**

You may inject environment variables into Mix by prefixing a key in your .env file with MIX_:

```
MIX_SENTRY_DSN_PUBLIC=http://example.com
```

After the variable has been defined in your .env file, you may access via the process.env object. If the value changes while you are running a watch task, you will need to restart the task:

```
process.env.MIX_SENTRY_DSN_PUBLIC
```

---

The most important thing to remember is that you have to use [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix) for this to work. Mix is what is injecting the environment variable.

Comment: You should also add `require('dotenv').config();` to the top of webpack.mix.js

Comment: thats worked for me without any require ... just add a new variable in env file with this prefix : MIX_  but need to restart php artisan serve and also restart npm run watch....

Comment: @Dazzle In my case, it doesn't work neither way  :/ with or without `require('dotenv').config();`

Comment: did you `npm install dotenv`? Try recompile or delete node_modules folder and reinstall

Answer (score 2):

```
 process.env.MIX_VAR /  process.env.MIX_STRIPE_KEY
```

It's will work without any settings. Just run this command

> npm run prod

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#environment-variables

However, you will need to restart the task if the environment variable's value changes while the task is running:
e.g If Watch is running then re-run it.

```
npm run watch
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Solution by official documentation.

You may use **Environment Variables** https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#environment-variables.

File `.env`:

```
VITE_SOME_NAME=some value
```

File `*.js`:

```
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_NAME);
```

### 2. My working solution by logic and practice.

Passing **any** static and dynamic parameters to the JS script.
Any script - not only modules!
Assembly in one file.

File `some_template-vue.blade.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Laravel + VUE</title>
    <script>
        window.scrf_token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
        window.services = {
            myService: {
                constFromClass:        '{{ App\Models\MyClass::CONST_NAME }}',
                valueFromENV:          '{{ env('SOME_PARAM', 'default value') }}',
                urlFromRoute:          '{{ route('some/url') }}',
                urlFromRouteWithParam: '{{ route('some/url', ['param' => 'value']) }}'
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As result you will get in output:

```
<script>
    window.scrf_token = 'AbCdEfAbCdEfAbCdEfAbCdEfAbCdEfAbCdEfAbCdEf';
    window.services = {
        myService: {
            constFromClass:        'some value from class',
            valueFromENV:          'some value from ENV',
            urlFromRoute:          'some URL from Route',
            urlFromRouteWithParam: 'some URL from Route with param'
        }
    }
</script>
```

### 3. The idea of a Single Center of Responsibility through official practices.

File `.env`:

```
VITE_SERVICE_URL="/get_service"
VITE_SERVICE_SOME_PARAM="some value"
```

File `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get(env('VITE_SERVICE_URL'), function () {
    return '<script type="module"> console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_SERVICE_SOME_PARAM); </script>';
})->name('service');
```

File `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
    // https://v4.vitejs.dev/config/#using-environment-variables-in-config
    // Load env file based on `mode` in the current working directory.
    // Set the third parameter to '' to load all env regardless of the `VITE_` prefix.
    const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');
    return {
        define: {
            __APP_ENV__: JSON.stringify(env.APP_ENV)
        },
        plugins: [
            vue(),
            laravel({
                input: [
                    'resources/css/app.css',
                    'resources/js/app.js'
                ],
                refresh: true,
            }),
        ]
    }
});
```